# Как стилизовать option в select?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы выбранный пункт был одного цвета, а остальные - другого.
Как на скрине. Как это сделать? P.S. Стрелку знаю как сделать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/9j9afsms/2/)

```
select, option:checked{
  color: blue;
}
option{
  color: black;
}
```